# Linear regression on pandas Dataframe with x values as index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-fitting

I have a Dataframe `df`:

```
[250 rows x 120 columns]
                    0         1         2         3         4         5   \
lag time [s]                                                               
0.041667      0.038638  0.193427  0.126253  0.058737  0.122129  0.117425   
0.083333      0.104397  0.323418  0.390540  0.194786  0.247005  0.242796   
0.125000      0.168620  0.577642  0.782489  0.389399  0.381930  0.325373   
0.166667      0.241057  0.912038  1.361542  0.560007  0.346316  0.343614   
0.208333      0.246506  0.636547  1.863711  0.767916  0.487872  0.203043   
...
```

I need to fit `y = a*x` with `x=df.index.values` the lag times for each column

Some columns may contain NaN, and would like to recover the different result in a 
`pd.DataFrame({'column' : [],'slope' : [], 'stderr' : [] })`

I could extract individually `x`, `y` data and fit the data using numpy `fitline()` but this looks to me tedious.

Is there a better way to do the job using panda ols?

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to retain the lag time as an index? The easiest way would probably be to incorporate it as a column in the dataframe and use statsmodels' formula interface:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

df2 = df.reset_index()

modres = {}
for colname in df2.drop('index', axis=1).columns:
    mod = sm.ols(formula=colname+' ~ index', data=df2)
    modres[colname] = mod.fit()
```

You asked for a dataframe of lists but I think it makes more sense to retain the whole results object from each of the regressions rather than throw away most of the info. My suggestion saves a dictionary of the regression results. To access the coefficients and standard errors for the `y1 ~ x` regression you would write `modres['y1'].params` and `modres['y1'].bse`.

If you introspect on the object you'll see that you can grab the AIC, t-stats, etc from each of the results objects. You can also pass them to a whole lot of other `statsmodels` functions for forecasting, backcasting and so on.

Comment: No problem, just let me know if that's not what you're looking for and I can tweak it.

Comment: Resetting adds a column to my df but I am confused with ols formula. I need  x to be the lag times and  fit every other columns to get one separate fit per column. How should I define my model ?

Comment: I could succeed doing :x = im.index.values # 


for (column_name, timeseries) in df.iterkv():
    
     mod = sm.ols(formula='timeseries ~ x', data=df)
     res = mod.fit()
     res.summary()

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your question closely enough the first time. Your approach is pretty good and I've revised my answer to provide something that is closer to what you want.

Comment: df.reset_index() creates a new column ,  previous indexe lag times [s] are now in axis 1.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit easier to construct the regression formula that way and each of your records is also guaranteed to have a unique index. Is  reindexing the dataframe undesirable in your application?

Comment: I need to keep column ids as float or int since they represents original objects. Pre treatment on df eliminates some undesirable columns. The last colum id reprsents the total number of original objet. Reindexing the df is not a problem sice it creates a new df object

Comment: First, I've left your original dataframe untouched so the reindexed dataframe is only used to construct the regressions. You could just think of `df2` as a temporary construction and use the original `df` in the rest of your calculations. Second, the reindexed dataframe should have the lags as a column of floats. Finally, if you did want to select on lags in the reindexed dataframe you could use eg. `df2[df2.index == 0.041667]`.